# ArcGIS Focal Statistics Circular Radius Bug Work-Around

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, focal-statistics

I am attempting to run focal statistics on a Raster with a circular neighborhood of 3 cells (600m radius), using the statistics type "maximum". Focal statistics calculates a seemingly nonsensical value for each pixel value. For example, most pixels have a value ~3.4, when all pixel in the radius have a value greater than 3000. I am running ArcGIS 10.4.1.

When a rectangular radius is used, the correct maximum value is selected by the focal statistics tool. Is this related to the known bug:

http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDU5NzI2

Any ideas on a work-around?

Comment: Create buffer and clip original. See output raster statistics. Also see if split raster tool can do it faster, it supports polygon geometries as split extents

Comment: Created a buffer and clipped the original. Output raster statistics were still incorrect. Could this have something to do with the Spatial Reference - "Undefined Sinusoidal" ?

Comment: What's the output raster format? Try basic grid saved in folder, no TIFF, no database raster

Comment: output raster format is basic grid in folder, no TIFF. Maybe pixel resolution is too high and causing errors for focal processing?